# Query to group data in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in MS Access:

```
ID        | Holiday
----------+------------------
1234      | 1
1234      | 2
2345      | 5
2345      | 6
```

I would like create a query to sum the Holiday for each duplicate IDs.

I would like to make my query result  like this:

```
ID        | Holiday
----------+------------------
1234      | 3
2345      | 11
```

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Perhaps using SQL  in MS Access
?
Good day people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, you just need to use `sum` and `group by`

```
select
    id,
    sum(holiday) as holiday
from yourTable
group by
    id
```